# How to lift a PartialFunction to Either

Tags: scala

There is no built-in function in the Scala API to lift a `PartialFunction` to `Either`.

Here is my version :

```
  def liftToEither[A, B, C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C) : A => Either[C, B] = { a =>
     if (pf.isDefinedAt(a)) Right(pf(a)) else Left(c(a))
  }
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: You cannot use built-in `Either.cond(pf.isDefinedAt(a), pf(a), c(a))` ? or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @kaktusito Yeah, this would work. But just like the OPs proposition, it will evaluate `pf` twice, which can be undesirable.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lift` and `toRight`. I'm not sure if I'd call it better.

```
def liftToEither[A, B, C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C) : A => Either[C, B] =
    a => pf.lift(a).toRight(c(a))
```

`lift` will transform `PartialFunction[A, B]` into `A => Option[B]`. Then we can apply that lifted function to `a` to obtain `Option[B]`, and use `toRight` to transform `Some(b)` to `Right(b)`, and apply `c` to `a` for instances of `None` to get the `Left(c(a))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution that just composes `PartialFunctions` (and doesn't create a closure on its own), try this:

```
def liftToEither[A, B, C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C) : A => Either[C, B] = {
  val fallback = PartialFunction((x: A) => Left(c(x)))
  pf.andThen(Right(_)).orElse(fallback)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }

def liftToEither[A, B, C]( pf: PartialFunction[ A, B ] )
                         ( c: A => C ) : A => Either[ C, B ] = { a =>
  val trial =  Try( pf( a ) )
  trial match {
    case Success( b ) => Right( b )
    case Failure( ex ) => Left( c(a) )
  } 
}
```